# Azure parent/child differencing disk

Tags: azure

I am testing Azure IaaS and have run into a pretty basic problem. I have a parent and child VHD that I have uploaded as page blobs with csupload, and there are images and disks showing in the portal. I then try to associate the parent with the child:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\2012-10\bin>csupload set-parent -child "visualstudio60-000001.vhd" -parent "visualstudio60.vhd"
Windows(R) Azure(TM) Upload Tool version 1.8.0.0
for Microsoft(R) .NET Framework 3.5
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Using the saved connection string...
The specified resource does not exist
```

How do I get the tool to see the disks are there? I've tried lots of different variations and can't get this simple task to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using IaaS VM and using "Csupload Set-Parent" then you are using wrong command. If you check the csuplaod help for set-parent command you will see that this command is only for old VM Role features which is still existed as below:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\2012-10>csupload get-help
 set-parent
Windows(R) Azure(TM) Upload Tool version 1.8.0.0
for Microsoft(R) .NET Framework 3.5
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

NAME
    Set-Parent

CATEGORY
    VmRole

SYNOPSIS
    Set the parent of an existing uploaded and commited VM image.

SYNTAX
    Set-Parent -Child <string> [-Connection SubscriptionId={subscriptionId};Cert
ificateThumbprint={subscriptionManagementCertificate};ServiceManagementEndpoint=
{azureManagementEndpoint}] -Parent <string>
```

In Windows Azure Virtual Machine (IaaS) you will uploaded multiple disks categorized as OS disks and Data Disks. Once you setup the OS/Data VHD correctly and upload either using PowerShell commands or directly from Portal you can create a Virtual Machine and add Data disk to it. 
The following links should help you:

- [Creating and Uploading a Virtual Hard Disk that Contains the Windows Server Operating System](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/upload-a-vhd/)
- [How to Attach a Data Disk to a Virtual Machine](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/attach-a-disk/)

Comment: OK, so IaaS doesn't support differencing disks?

Comment: I have confirmed through another channel that you cannot do differencing disks.